# Wheel colliders detach when AI Car is not in view

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

My camera follows a specific car around the track. When the camera isn’t looking at the other cars then it looks like the colliders for the wheels from another car detach and get left somewhere then cars collide with them and stop dead…

[Collision view showing wheel colliders from another car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joBRO.png)

I tried attaching a camera to my ai driven car. This works well but the cars that are not in view seem to detach their wheel colliders and then my ai driven car and others collide with these colliders when visually there is nothing there.